# Trouble with a simple loop in Matlab

Tags: matlab, for-loop

I have a logical mask of pixels `e1` that need to be "blended". No matter what value I put for `k`, loop executes `k` times but image is only affected once.
Code:

```
for k=1:5 %I want to do it 5 times but it does the action only once.
    for i=2:rows-1
        for j=2:cols-1
            if e1(i, j) == 1 %if mask == 1, I take "marked" pixel, 8 pixel surrounding it, and avg them.
                I2(i, j, 1) = (I2(i, j-1, 1) + I2(i, j+1, 1) + I2(i-1, j, 1) + I2(i-1, j-1, 1) + I2(i-1, j+1, 1) + I2(i+1, j, 1) + I2(i+1, j+1, 1) + I2(i+1, j-1, 1))/8;
                I2(i, j, 2) = (I2(i, j-1, 2) + I2(i, j+1, 2) + I2(i-1, j, 2) + I2(i-1, j-1, 2) + I2(i-1, j+1, 2) + I2(i+1, j, 2) + I2(i+1, j+1, 2) + I2(i+1, j-1, 2))/8;
                I2(i, j, 3) = (I2(i, j-1, 3) + I2(i, j+1, 3) + I2(i-1, j, 3) + I2(i-1, j-1, 3) + I2(i-1, j+1, 3) + I2(i+1, j, 3) + I2(i+1, j+1, 3) + I2(i+1, j-1, 3))/8;
            end
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: That behavior will be expected if all your '1' elements in the e1 image is unconnected. If so, more than one pass over I2 will not produce different results, as no neighboring points are changed.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try:

```
for k=1:5
  I2=convn(I2,[1 1 1;1 0 1;1 1 1]/8);
end
```